Averaging Binned Values from AWS Timestream in Grafana
I'm pulling data from AWS Timestream to visualize in Grafana. I've set up a custom dashboard variable for $interval that I mostly keep set to auto. I'm attempting to bin the values on an AVG, but unless I'm completely misunderstanding something I can't get the AVG to line up with my manual calculations.

The green line here is the raw data, the yellow line is the calculated average using the binned time. As you can see, the average line is raising before the next green dot jumps up, as well as sinks back down before the green dot jumps down again. For reference, here is the raw data:



timestamp
raw data




15:54:14
908


15:55:59
933


15:57:34
1096


15:58:04
3151


15:58:39
3056


15:59:09
3148


15:59:45
3148


16:01:29
961



This is the outcome of the average and what I would expect (given the interval should be an average of the data before the interval timestamp and the last interval timestamp):



timestamp
calculated avg
expected avg




15:54:00
921
909


15:56:00
1096
920


15:58:00
3126
1096


16:00:00
961
3126


16:02:00
917
961



Finally, here is the SQL query that I am using:
SELECT 
  BIN(time, ${interval}) as binned_time, 
  meter, 
  AVG(measure_value::double) as average_value
FROM 
  $__database.$__table 
WHERE 
  $__timeFilter 
  AND meter = '$meter'
GROUP BY 
  BIN(time, ${interval}), meter
ORDER BY 
  binned_time

Why is the average not lining up as I would expect / what am I doing wrong here? I'm really not sure how they aren't lining up correctly with the timestamps.

I think your expectation stems from possibly wrong understanding of how Bin works. Notice that your expected values are simply shifted one rowfrom actual ones. I guess(!) you expect bin returning last second of associated interval, but it seems(!) like it in fact returns the first second. This results in values being grouped to the left, and graph looking a bit predictive.

@markalex yes that would make sense. Do you have any suggestions on how I could approach shifting the average to make more sense with the raw data and the intervals? Or is this the expected way to handle what I'm trying to do?
